# Prisma Explicit Many to Many - how to delete item without deleting user

Tags: postgresql, orm, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

**My use case is simple:**

- There's users
- Users can create workspaces
- Users can delete workspaces
- User gets a role on each workspace (`OWNER`, `ADMIN`, `MANAGER`, `VIEWER`)

**The problem:**

This requires an **explicit** `many-to-many` relation (`users` <-> `workspaces`).

Creating workspaces is fine, it all works. Deleting a workspace is where the problem occurs. It either:

- Deletes nothing
- Or deletes everything (`user` + `workspace` + `their relation table row`) using `onDelete: Cascade`

**I obviously don't want my users to get deleted.**

Here's my Prisma schema:

```
model User {
  id                 String              @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt          DateTime            @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime            @updatedAt
  email              String?             @unique
  plan               Plan?               @relation(fields: [planId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  planId             String?
  workspaces         WorkspacesOnUsers[]
}

model Workspace {
  id           String              @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt    DateTime            @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime            @updatedAt
  name         String?
  users        WorkspacesOnUsers[]
}

model WorkspacesOnUsers {
  id          String     @id @default(cuid())
  user        User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict)
  userId      String?
  workspace   Workspace? @relation(fields: [workspaceId], references: [id])
  workspaceId String?
  role        Role?      @default(VIEWER)
}

enum Role {
  OWNER
  ADMIN
  MANAGER
  VIEWER
}
```

And this is how I try to delete a workspace from a user:

```js
await prisma.workspace.delete({
  where: { id: workspaceId },
})
```

I also tried this but it only removes the row in the relation, but I still can't remove the workspace after that (`Foreign key constraint failed on the field: WorkspacesOnUsers_userId_fkey (index)`):

```js
  await prisma.workspace.update({
    where: { id: workspaceId },
    data: {
      users: { deleteMany: {} },
    },
  })
```

Someone help please!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with users deleting posts, this is how I deleted a post attached to a user via there id (in this case their sessionId)

```
await prisma.user.update({
    where: { sessionId: sessionId },
    data: {
        Post: {
            delete: {
                id: postId,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

in your case it will look something like this

```
await prisma.user.update({
    where: { id: userIdFromFunction },
    data: {
        Workspace: {
            delete: {
                id: workspaceIdFromFunction,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Hope this helps!